Why is it hard to get 考虑 from the keyboard?
I try to enter "kaolu" on the windows chinese keyboard and also on Google translate and hoped that I would be able to quickly find what seems to be a common word but no, it is hard.
Am I mistaken, and the word 考虑 is actually not so often used?
考 was ok to find on the keyboard selections
虑 however, I had to give up and just draw.


This question is similar to: How do I type the lü for Character Romanization?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Because it is "kaolü" rather than "kaolu" in pinyin.
Since most keyboard doesn't have the "ü" key, the pinyin input method recognizes the "v" key as "ü". You have to type "kaolv" to get 考虑.

The Chinese language has 6 mono-vowels (monophthongs), which are (阿 哦 鹅 衣 屋 鱼). The committee of the Pinyin scheme (1958) determined to use the Latin alphabet (as in English) for Chinese Romanization. The alphabet has 26 letters from a to z, including 5 vowel letters (a o e i u). They use the 5 vowel letters for the first 5 Chinese vowels (阿 哦 鹅 衣 屋). Then they must figure out how to represent the sixth vowel (鱼). Finally, they used an extra symbol (ü) for (鱼).
If it was not the worst result, they made things even worse. They decided to use the letter u to substitute the letter (or symbol) ü according to a few complicated rules, which caused a lot of difficulties for people to learn and use the Pinyin system.
About 40 years later, computers and the internet are becoming more and more popular. Pinyin has become a great tool for people to input Chinese characters. Because, in most alphabet keyboards, there is no symbol ü, many software companies just use the letter v as the key of this extra symbol.
For example, in a Microsoft keyboard,
(1) Both yu and yv are for 鱼, but lu is for 路, while lv is for 虑.
(2) Both yue and yve are for 月.
(3) Both lue and lve are for 略。luo is for 落.

考虑 kǎo lǜ - Window Chinese keyboard inputs - "kao‘lv".
Note that typing "v" to get the special character "ǜ" is a special case.
How to type "ǜ"
